# Скачивание и сохранение пути к картинке в sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android-studio, android-asynctask, download, android-scoped-storage

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой сохранения пути к картинке в sharedPreference. Класс DownloadImageTask еще устанавливает в ImageView фото(это было его основной задачей, но потом стало нужно сохранять фото и путь к нему в памяти устройства). AS просто не видит метод `getSharedPreferences(XML_PHOTO, MODE_PRIVATE)`. Помогите, пожалуйста)
Класс загрузки фото:

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urlDisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        SharedPreferences photoSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(XML_PHOTO, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor photoEditor = photoSharedPreferences.edit();
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myBitmap.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        photoEditor.putString(SAVED_PHOTO_URI, file.getAbsolutePath()).apply();
    }
}
```

Его вызов в onCreate:

```
if (photoSharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_PHOTO_URI, "").length() < 1) {
            new DownloadImageTask(profileImage).execute(URL_WITHOUT_API + photoSharedPreferences.getString(SAVED_PHOTO_URL, ""));
}
```

Comment: Это уже становится каким то FAQ - попытки в Android'е писать во внешнюю память практически все обречены на провал. Скоро я думаю совсем все уберут. Пишите в другое место!

Comment: Куда именно? И почему попытки обрачены на провал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корень зла лежит здесь:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Если вы прочтете диагностику компилятора, то заметите, что метод объявлен как `deprecated`, что означает в переводе на язык простых смертных: **не пишите больше во внешнюю память!**

А почему? Да потому что так решил Google.

Теперь, куда все таки можно писать?

1. Писать в приватное место самого приложения: `Context.getFilesDir()`
2. Писать в выделенное для проги место во внешней памяти (начиная с Android Q тоже уже закрыто) - `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`
3. Писать в публичные места типа `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` - тоже с недавнего времени закрыт
4. Писать в `shared` ресурсы. Теперь это единственный православный способ. Читайте документацию по [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage)